# Studio 2010 Express C#, created class not visible in another file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, express

I am attempting to get Scs (simple client/server code from  here: http://www.halilibrahimkalkan.com/en/page/SCS-(Simple-Client-Server)-Framework.aspx ) to work with forms.
I have three projects in a single solution btw on Visual studio 2010 express. This works fine so long as I just run the more simple console based applications of the server + client.
I CANNOT get my Form1 (simply inherited from Windows.Form) to be 'visible' from a file (program.cs) in the client project. It's baffelling.
I have uploaded the whole project to here  http://filecloud.io/qg1blte3

as I don't know which 'bit of it' to put in here to show the problem.
I am simply getting the Error:
    The type or namespace name 'Form1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Documents and Settings\Myself\Desktop\Scs-Sources\Scs-Sources\Scs-Samples\SimpleCalculatorSystem\CalculatorClient\Program.cs

I have added 'using' in all the correct places.
All projects are in the same namespace.

I am a newby amateur and this is my first question so that means you have to be EASY ON ME!!!
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Don't upload whole project, give us just the code, we can't see what you in your PC. Also, try to make public what is not visibile.

Comment: I cannot show 'only the code' as the whole thing it too long and complicated. Another problem I am having (this may be the cause of the problem) it that when I type (at the top of a number of code files) using System.Windows.Forms;       Error 3 The type or namespace name 'Windows' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference) I will attempt to put an reference to windows in the other projects (If I can, I am somewhat out of my depth).Thanks, Gerry

Comment: Added refs to all projects and can now put System.Windows.Forms in OK but original problem still exists.